# Weird rendering with Xamarin Forms in release mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting a weird black edge around clickable items in the android emulator
when testing in release mode. Also happens on devices when deployed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem was I needed to update my JDK...or at least I think. If you come across check for java updates.